# How to access jmeter variable in pepper-box producer?

Tags: java, jmeter, apache-kafka

I am trying to test my kafka-cluster using jmeter and pepper-box pluging.

I am using jmeter and pepper-box plugin for the first time.so excuse me if you feel i am asking some non-sense questions.

I have written a Bean shell pre-processor and there i put **UUID** in a variable and mark it as jmeter variable

```
import java.util.UUID;
vars.put("msgUuid",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

now when i am trying to use this variable in my pepper box producer and use this "msgUuid" variable in it then it gives me error saying

> symbol:   variable msgUuid   location: class
>   MessageIterator1530514979627 1 error Uncaught Exception
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file. See log file for
>   details.

The sample producer is

```
{
 "message_id": "${{msgUuid}}",
 "type": "chat",
 "sender": "xxx",
 "receiver": "yyy",
 "stype": "text",
 "xml": "message"
 "timestamp": "{{TIMESTAMP()}}"
}
```

Can you please guide me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is not possible with the current pepper box plugin.So we have to look for other way out.

Answer (score -1):

You should refer to Jmeter variables like this `${msgUuid}` **NOT** `${{msgUuid}}`.

Also you can use Jmeter function `${__UUID}`directly instead of using beanshell code.

You can find more information about jmeter variables and functions in [Jmeter usermanual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)